# css background-image How to go up a few unkonwn levels to specific folder name in the src path of a URL?

Tags: html, css

I have a component and the name of parent folder (not a dircet parent) and i want to access a file that is located under that parent folder.

If that parent folder is the direct parent of the component i would do the following to access the wanted file:

```
background-image: url('../images/bg.png');
```

But how can i get that file If i dont know how many levels up the parent folder 
something like is positioned in reference to my compnent.

It should be something like the following:

```
background-image: url('**/images/bg.png');
```

Comment: you'd have to use an absolute url... i.e. http://www.somesite.com/folder/asset.jpg

Comment: If you don't know how many levels up it is you won't be able to use a relative path

Comment: You can't- an unknown depth would involve the browser or some other entity searching through folders, which presents multitudes of security and uniformity problems. URL = uniform resource locator